# Safari jumpy background size calculation on window resize

Tags: html, css, safari, background-size

I have a 100% width background image on the body.

this image

[image: https://imgur.com/C56S1lS]

and the css

```
body {
    background-image: url('../images/bg-width.gif');
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

you see here when I resize the window **in safari**, it doesn't calculate the height and width proportionately, it squishes the width a bit and then jumps to whatever next increment, resulting in a jagged resizing that messes with other aspects of my site design that rely on the proportion of the grid size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZkqU.jpg

whereas in chrome, as show below, the scaling is proportional and smooth

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XBUf.jpg

Anyone have any insight into why this happens, and perhaps how I can prevent it?

driving me crazy!

(would embed my images but don't have the rep!)

Comment: I don't know how to fix this exact problem, but I did a workaround by making the background image repeat as a graphic as opposed to doing it with css.

Comment: still curious though!